# OneDrive SDK or Windows Toolkit OneDrive service on Xbox One

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, xbox-one

After being published, my apps retro failed certification because one uses the OneDrive SDK and the other uses Toolkit's OneDrive service to authenticate on the Xbox One.  Microsoft Support provided the following policy:

> 10.13.4
>
> Products published to Xbox One must not:
>
> Request or store Microsoft Account usernames or passwords.

However, the SDKs do not request the Microsoft Account username or password, nor does it provide either in unencrypted form to developers.  I checked Microsoft's OneDrive app on the Xbox One and I'm not entirely sure which service it is using to authenticate, but it does not appear to be using the XBox Live SDK.  My question is, why can't either SDKs be used on Xbox One to authenticate?  Why are developers being forced to use Xbox Live to authenticate when Microsoft does not use Xbox Live for their own apps?

Comment: Did you use the windows community toolkit for this ?

Comment: I am using it for one app, the other the OneDrive SDK.  It doesn't matter though, if you aren't using the Xbox Live SDK, they are retro failing apps.

Comment: I can understand the requirement to solely use the Xbox Live SDK for Xbox One Games, but it makes no sense for UWP apps on the Xbox One platform.